# .net Data encryption? Which classes to use?

Tags: .net, encryption

I am looking into how to encrypt data in .net.

After some reading decided on to use AES encryption as it's well establised standard and adoped by almost all organizations.

Now i am hunting for how to encrypt data using AES and getting some conflicting results. .Net has classes for AES as well as for Rijndael.

**If any one has worked with it could you please share which classes i can use?** I found some samples for Rijndael but not for AES.

Technically AES is Rijndael implementation so what is the differences between those two?

Comment: Rijndael actually defines a family of encryption algorithms and AES is a specific subset of these selected by the U.S. NIST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the Namespace part of the question, use:

[System.Security.Cryptography.Aes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx)

Also, here is a link to a blog post that demonstrates the AesManaged class:

[Simple Cryptography Block](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevesheldon/archive/2008/10/25/simple-cryptography-block.aspx)

The code takes a string, encrypts it using the AesManaged wrapper, then converts it to Base64 (which you can comment out if you don't wan't that functionality).

Answer (score 2):

Just addressing the question on the differences? I found one article here:

[The Differences Between Rijndael and AES](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2006/10/09/The-Differences-Between-Rijndael-and-AES.aspx)

Excerpt:

> Essentially, if you want to use
>   RijndaelManaged as AES you need to
>   make sure that:
>
> 1. The block size is set to 128 bits
> 2. You are not using CFB mode, or if you are the feedback size is also
>      128 bits

Comment: Thanks that explains it, Unfortunatly i can't mark multiple answers but this is part of answer.

Comment: No worries, I'm not expecting this to be the accepted one. :)